# "curl: command not found" on Debian 10 with PHP 7.3 installed successfully?

Tags: debian, curl, php7, debian-buster

I have a Debian 10 VPS where I'm configuring for use for an internal app. At the moment I'm installing a monitoring package for the server which requires me to use `curl`. Running the command returns the following error:

> -bash: curl: command not found

The server itself runs PHP 7.3, and I went to run the command `apt-get install php7.3-curl`, which returned the following message:

> php7.3-curl is already the newest version (7.3.4-2).

I could install the PHP 5.6 version of curl, but I don't want to be in this situation - especially as PHP 7.3 Curl is already installed.

Am I missing something from my configuration?

Comment: `php7.3-curl` is not curl. curl has its own package.

Comment: Don't you need cURL `curl`, instead of php-curl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php7.3-curl is the package to do curl in php.
If you want to use curl directly in terminal you need install curl (apt-get install curl)